# Publishing .jar to private maven with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, grails, gradle

I am working on publishing a Grails plugin (ultimately a .jar) to a private maven repo is resulting in the following error.  I have confirmed multiple times the credentials are valid.

It seems as if the credentials aren't being sent at all (**Unauthorized 401**):

```
Could not transfer artifact com.blah.plugins:blahCommonPlugin:pom:0.1 from/to remote (http://maven.blah.com): Could not write to resource 'com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1/blahCommonPlugin-0.1.pom'
:publishMavenJavaPublicationToBlahRepository FAILED
:publishMavenJavaPublicationToBlahRepository (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 2.788 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToBlahRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'blah'
   > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.blah.plugins:blahCommonPlugin:jar:0.1 from/to remote (http://maven.blah.com): Could not write to resource 'com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1/blahCommonPlugin-0.1.jar'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.634 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
Could not PUT 'http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1/blahCommonPlugin-0.1.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

In my build.gradle I have the following (only relevant parts):

```
version "0.1"
group "com.blah.plugins"

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name "blah"
            url "http://maven.blah.com"
        }
    }
}

//Not sure if I need this
grailsPublish {
    repo = 'blah'
    githubSlug = 'blah/blahCommonPlugin'
    title = "blahCommonPlugin"
    desc = "blahcommon plugin"
    developers = [erikahlswede:"Erik Ahlswede"]
}
```

Then I have this in my settings.xml (~/.m2/settings.xml)

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>blah</id>
      <username>un</username>
      <password>pass</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Any idea what I could be missing?

**EDIT 1**

I removed settings.xml to debug for now.  I am using:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            name "snapshots"
            url "http://maven.blah.com/"
            credentials {
                username 'blahUser'
                password 'blahPassword'
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
                digest(DigestAuthentication)
            }
        }
}
```

And with verbose output I see:

```
Using Credentials [username: blahUser] for authenticating against 'null:-1' using Digest
Using Credentials [username: blahUser] for authenticating against 'null:-1' using Basic
```

Here is the rest of the relevant log:

```
Publishing to repository org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@457d1e38
Using Credentials [username: blahUser] for authenticating against 'null:-1' using Digest
Using Credentials [username: blahUser] for authenticating against 'null:-1' using Basic
Deploying to http://maven.blah.com/
Downloading: com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from repository remote at http://maven.blah.com/
Constructing external resource: http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Performing HTTP GET: http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Connection request: [route: {}->http://maven.blah.com][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://maven.blah.com][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
Connecting to maven.blah.com:80
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: GET /com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://maven.blah.com] can be kept alive indefinitely
Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://maven.blah.com][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml]
Could not find metadata com.blah.plugins:blahCommonPlugin:0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in remote (http://maven.blah.com/)
Uploading: com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/blahCommonPlugin-0.1-20160405.174228-1.jar to repository remote at http://maven.blah.com/
Attempting to put resource http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/blahCommonPlugin-0.1-20160405.174228-1.jar.
Upload http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/blahCommonPlugin-0.1-20160405.174228-1.jar
Performing HTTP PUT: http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/blahCommonPlugin-0.1-20160405.174228-1.jar
Connection request: [route: {}->http://maven.blah.com][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://maven.blah.com][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
Stale connection check
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: PUT /com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/blahCommonPlugin-0.1-20160405.174228-1.jar HTTP/1.1
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Authentication required
maven.blah.com:80 requested authentication
Authorization challenge processed
Authentication failed
```

**EDIT 2**

Tried just curling the request...doesn't seem to work:

```
$ curl --basic -u username:password http://maven.blah.com/com/blah/plugins/blahCommonPlugin/test/api-1.0-20160128.114425-1.jar --request PUT --data blahCommonPlugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I found our maven server's nginx configuration.  Not sure if this is configured correctly.  Does this look okay?:

```
# Allow only these methods (GET and HEAD are allowed by default)
dav_methods PUT MKCOL;
dav_access user:rw  group:rw  all:r;
create_full_put_path on;
...
 # For all plugins and directories
location / {
    # Allow files listing for repositories
    autoindex on;

    limit_except PUT MKCOL {
        # For GET and HEAD request use this file for username/password who have only download permissions from Maven server
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd/downloaders;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `gradle` does not engage settings for credentials. How sure are you that setting's username/password are used?

Comment: Added EDIT 1.  Verbose logs shows "Using Credentials [username: blahUser] for authenticating against 'null:-1' using Basic"

Answer (score 1):

This is how we are handling publishing to maven repo with credentials:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://repo"){
                authentication(userName: "yankee", password: "doodle")
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "http://repo-snapshotRepository"){
                authentication(userName: "yankee", password: "doodle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More detail can be found here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

Comment: Turns out there is a separate user for actually PUT requests which is why Authentication was failing.  Hope all is well ;D